# html table and Javascript to add new table under this

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have the following html code which is a table including some fields about the education of a user.

```
<table border="0" style="margin: auto; ">

<td width="60%" >

<fieldset style="width:530px; padding-left:5px; background-color:white " >

    <INPUT type="button" value="Add new Table" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    School/University/College*</br>
    <input name="school_1" type="text" size="73"/>
    </br></br>
    Field of Study</br>
    <input name="field_1" type="text" size="73"/>
    </br></br>
    Specialized subjects</br>
    <input name="specialized_subject_1" type="text" size="73" />
    </br></br>
    Degree</br>
    <input name="degree_1" type="text" size="73"/>
    </br></br>
    Grade</br>
    <input name="grade_1" type="text" size="73" />
    </br></br></br>

        Attended from:&nbsp;<select name="month_1_1"> 
        <option value=" "> EMPTY </option> 
        <option value="January">January</option> 
        </select>

        <select id="year_1_1" name="year_1_1"> 
        <option value=" "> EMPTY </option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
       </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        Until:&nbsp;<select name="month_1_2"> 
        <option value=" "> EMPTY </option> 
        <option value="January">January</option>                        
        </select>

        <select name="year_1_2"> 
        <option value=" "> EMPTY </option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
       </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;    

    </h2></font>
    </fieldset>

</td>

</table>
```

I am using the following Javascript code in order for the user to add a new table under this, to add more details about his education in case he wants to do it. My Javascript code is not working. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
   <SCRIPT language="javascript">
      function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
            }
        }
    }


</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: which error do you get in the console?

Comment: add field button does not do anything at all when I press it

Comment: I mean the javascript console... Nevermind, I just runned locally and saw the error. Writing the answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this:

```
<table border="0" style="margin: auto; ">
```

with this:

```
<table border="0" style="margin: auto;" id="dataTable">
```

whenever you don't figure out what is the error in a javascript code, you should check the console. I don't know which browser you're using for debugging, but you may check [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) where to find the javascript console.

your javascript was throwing this error in my console:

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'table.rows')
```

which means `table` was `null`. As you define table with `getElementById` I just saw the id didn't actually existed in the html page.

To further reply your question about limiting the number of tables, wrap your entire code in an if statement and declare a global variable.

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
var counter = 0;

if (counter > 9)
alert("can't add more");
else {

counter++;

// paste your actual JS code here


}

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: perfect...by the way do you have any idea how I can modify the code so that the user can add only 9 more tables...so in totaly to be 10 tables. thanks...

Comment: just add a global variable 'counter', add use counter++ every time you add a table. If counter > 9 then alert("you can't add more tables"); otherwise, add the table.